# UIKit programmatically: Scrollview and stack views

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a stackview, nested in a stackview, nested in a scrollView.

card is a StackView, and vStackContainer is a StackView, both nested inside a scrollview.
For some reason when I try to duplicate the card and present it on screen, I only get one and not more, if I try to switch the card with a normal UILabel, it works fine.
Why is that?

Card code:

```
let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = ColorsConstants.secondary
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.spacing = 15
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
        v.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        return v
}()
```

vStackContainer code:

```
let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.spacing = 20
        v.distribution = .equalSpacing
        return v
}()
```

viewDidLoad:

```
 view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(vStackContainer)
        vStackContainer.addArrangedSubview(mainLabel)
        
        for _ in 0...<15 {
            card.addArrangedSubview(cardImage)
            card.addArrangedSubview(cardTitle)
            card.addArrangedSubview(cardDifficulty)
            vStackContainer.addArrangedSubview(card)
        }
```

Again, swapping the `card` StackView with a regular UILabel gives me 15 labels on screen, but the code above only renders one card on screen.

Comment: You can't add the same view to a stackView more than once. If you want 15 cards displayed you need to create 15 separate instances of card views.

Comment: @RobC Aha, I see, I'm sure there's a DRY way to do it tho, what would be your approach on it?

Comment: Just implement some factory methods: makeCardStack(), makeCardImage(), makeCardTitle() and iterate over them in your loop.

Comment: @RobC Okay that make sense, thanks!